# pure ruby: calculate sparse matrix rank fast(er)

Tags: ruby, matrix, sparse-matrix, sketchup

### How do I speed up the rank calculation of a sparse matrix in pure ruby?

I'm currently calculating the rank of a matrix (std lib) to determine the rigidity of a graph.
That means I have a sparse matrix of about 2 rows * 9 columns to about 300 rows * 300 columns.
That translates to times of several seconds to determine the rank of the matrix, which is very slow for a GUI application.
Because I use Sketchup I am bound to Ruby 2.0.0.
I'd like to avoid the hassle of setting up gcc on windows, so nmatrix is (I think) not a good option.

**Edit:**
Example matrix:

```
[[12, -21, 0, -12, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [12, -7, -20, 0, 0, 0, -12, 7, 20],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 14, -20, 0, -14, 20]]
```

**Edit2:**
I am using integers instead of floats to speed it up considerably.
I have also added a fail fast mechanism earlier in the code in order to not call the slow `rank` function at all.

**Edit3:**
Part of the code

```
def rigid?(proto_matrix, nodes)
    matrix_base = Array.new(proto_matrix.size) { |index|
      # initialize the row with 0
      arr = Array.new(nodes.size * 3, 0.to_int)
      proto_row = proto_matrix[index]
      # ids of the nodes in the graph
      node_ids = proto_row.map { |hash| hash[:id] }
      # set the values of both of the nodes' positions
      [0, 1].each { |i|
        vertex_index = vertices.find_index(node_ids[i])
        # predetermined vector associated to the node
        vec = proto_row[i][:vec]
        arr[vertex_index * 3] = vec.x.to_int
        arr[vertex_index * 3 + 1] = vec.y.to_int
        arr[vertex_index * 3 + 2] = vec.z.to_int
      }
      arr
    }
    matrix = Matrix::rows(matrix_base, false)
    rank = matrix.rank
    # graph is rigid if the rank of the matrix is bigger or equal
    # to the amount of node coordinates minus the degrees of freedom
    # of the whole graph
    rank >= nodes.size * 3 - 6
end
```

Comment: Can you add a code sample?

Comment: Without code this is pure speculation. Define "very slow". Show what you've tried to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure the code matters, because the slow thing (I already measured) is the `matrix.rank` calculation.
I added an example matrix (I'm already using Integer values to speed it up considerably).

Comment: First note is that it should be `Array.new` as `::` is a namespace separator not intended for calling methods. It works, but it's against convention and reads strangely.

Comment: Are you computing a new `Matrix` each time you evaluate this function? If your source data never changes you'd want to generate one and save it somewhere to be evaluated later on repeatedly.

Comment: thx for the hint, but I do want to recalculate every time that the function is called (there might have been additions to the graph and it is called infrequently)
I guess I could add caching, but the rank function is so expensive that it's not worth the effort IMHO

Comment: @tadman thanks. my C++ background shining through :-D